# Нужно улучшить sql запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

У меня есть такие таблицы:
Группы:

```
id
name
```

и
Участники группы:

```
id
groupId
memberId
```

У нас имеется id пользователя.
Нужно получить список групп на которые он подписан с количеством подписчиков группы и имени группы.
У меня есть такой sql запрос для получения списка групп но не могу получить количество подписчиков групп:

```
SELECT g.gid, g.name
  FROM groups g, groupmembers gm
  WHERE gm.memberId = 1 AND g.gid = gm.groupId
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select g.gid, g.name, count(1)
  from groups g, groupmembers gm
 where g.gid in(select groupId from groupmembers where memberId = 1)
   and g.gid = gm.groupId
 group by g.gid, g.name
```

И если что, в таблице `groupmembers` собственная колонка `id` не нужна. гораздо лучше будет, если в ней будет только 2 колонки и обе они будут в составе первичного ключа (primary key). Потому как сейчас у вас наверняка не поддерживается уникальность связки user-gid и в одну группу можно включить одного и того же пользователя много раз.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял нужно удалить id из groupmembers и указать groupId и memberId как первичный ключ. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да. составной первичный ключ из двух столбцов. create table groupmembers (groupId ..., memberId ..., primary key (groupId, memberId), foreign ...)

Comment: Спасибо вам за дополнительное сведения